# Microsoft Access VBA - Run time error '3075'

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I've encountered the run time error '3075'. I'm a novice in VBA! >.< Can i know where did it went wrong? I can't solve it...

For e.g, if I enter a name "Sally" into a textbox (txtMainName), upon clicking on the search button the error pops-up.

The error:

Run-time error '3075':

Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression ' And [Main Applicant Name] Like 'Sally'".

```
Public Sub Search_Record()

Dim stDocName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String
Dim stLinkCriteria1 As String
Dim stLinkCriteria2 As String


    stLinkCriteria = ""
    stDocName = "frmDisplayInfo"

    If (Me!txtMainName <> "") Then
        stLinkCriteria1 = "[Main Applicant Name] Like ' " & Me![txtMainName] & "'"
        stLinkCriteria = stLinkCriteria & " And " & stLinkCriteria1
    End If

    If (Me!txtIDNo <> "") Then
        stLinkCriteria2 = "[ID No] Like ' " & Me![txtIDNo] & "'"
        stLinkCriteria = stLinkCriteria & " And " & stLinkCriteria2
    End If

    '(*This part is highlighted*)
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria
    DoCmd.Maximize

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the content of `stLinkCriteria` (the *actual* value it contains, *not* what you *think* it contains) when you get to `DoCmd.OpenForm`? (Set a breakpoint at the `OpenForm` line, run to that point, and look at what `stLinkCriteria` is when you get there.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Runtime error 3975` is `Invalid operator`, according to a quick Google search on `access vba runtime error 3075` (which you could have made yourself).

The problem is that you only assign a value of `""` to `stCriteria`.  If the first `if` statement executes, `stCriteria` is then assigned the value of `stCriteria AND  stCriteria1`, which is invalid.

The same thing happens if the second `if` statement is executed. (In fact, if both are actually run, `stCriteria` now contains `AND stCriteria1 AND stCriteria2`, which is even worse.)

The solution is to modify your code to only add the `AND` if it's needed:

```
stLinkCriteria = ""
stDocName = "frmDisplayInfo"

If (Me!txtMainName <> "") Then
    stLinkCriteria = "[Main Applicant Name] Like ' " & Me![txtMainName] & "'"
End If

If (Me!txtIDNo <> "") Then
    If stLinkCriteria <> "" then
        stLinkCriteria = stLinkCriteria & " AND "
    End If
    stLinkCriteria2 = "[ID No] Like ' " & Me![txtIDNo] & "'"
    stLinkCriteria = stLinkCriteria & " And " & stLinkCriteria2
End If
```

For future reference, the way to solve these kind of problems is to actually examine the value of the variable (in this case `stCriteria`) just before the line causing the error (here, it's the `DoCmd.OpenForm` line) executes. You do so by setting a breakpoint on the line where the error happens, running your app until the breakpoint is hit, and then examining the value of the variable. This shows you *exactly* what the variable contains, which can reveal the problem.

Comment: Thanks very much! It works, but i think you've missed out a 'End If'. The explaination is clear, I can now understand what went wrong.

Comment: Yep, I did. I'll fix it. Thanks. :-)

Comment: back to where i stopped... how can i display my records? the textbox doesnt shows the results i want...

Comment: I don'r know. Nothing in your question asked about display ing the results, which means that's a new, separate question.

Answer (score 3):

From the logic, it seems like your stLinkCriteria is starting with "and" which is causing the error:

You probably should put:

```
If (Me!txtMainName <> "") Then

    stLinkCriteria1 = "[Main Applicant Name] Like ' " & Me![txtMainName] & "'"

    if stLinkCriteria <> "" then                   <==== add this

       stLinkCriteria = stLinkCriteria & " and "   <==== and this

    end if                                         <==== and this

    stLinkCriteria = stLinkCriteria & stLinkCriteria1  <=== change this

End If
```

Hope that works - otherwise, the logic looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error from an extra space between a dot and the field name in:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE  cp  INNER JOIN [char_lib] ON [cp]. [library_id]  = [char_lib].[id] set..
```

Note to Microsoft: please create more precise and useful error messages. Thanks. I've no doubt you'll get right on this.