# Runtime Error 3075 while excution vba query ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hi guys iam getting this error when i try to Excute RunSql method , This is my query

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim strSQL As String
    x = Me.PONumber
    strSQL = "DELETE TblPoMaterials.PONumber, TblPoMaterials.ProductionDate, TblPoMaterials.AcceptedNumber, TblPoMaterials.RejectedNumber, TblPoMaterials.Shift " & vbCrLf & _
    "FROM TblPoMaterials " & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE (((TblPoMaterials.PONumber)=" & x & ") AND ((TblPoMaterials.ProductionDate)=[Forms]![FrmProductionEdit]![Zdate]) AND ((TblPoMaterials.AcceptedNumber)=[Forms]![FrmProductionEdit]![AcceptedProduct]) AND ((TblPoMaterials.RejectedNumber)=[Forms]![FrmProductionEdit]![RejectedProduct]) AND ((TblPoMaterials.Shift)=[Forms]![FrmProductionEdit]![Shift]));"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

The main idea is to pass the variable x as criteria for the previous query , I tried to use

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery strSQL
```

I know it’s not right but i just tried to see what happens , it produced a different runtime error.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit question to show the exact error message. Is PONumber a number type field? If not, need apostrophe delimiters: `='" & x & "')`. Or reference PONumber parameter same way as the other parameters.

Comment: PoNumber Field Is number , About the error message it’s gone after i added dim x as integer the declaration was in wrong place in the code thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Access VBA - Run time error '3075'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064203/microsoft-access-vba-run-time-error-3075)

Answer (score 1):

Simply include the `x` value as parameter in your query like you do other form controls. This way you avoid any concatenation. Below assumes `Me.PONumber` is a control on `FrmProductionEdit`. If not, adjust to correct form name. Also, the columns in `DELETE` clause is redundant as rows are deleted according to `WHERE` logic regardless of listed columns. Finally, table alias is used to avoid repetition of long table name and redundant parentheses are removed.

```vb
strSQL = "DELETE " & vbCrLf & _
         "FROM TblPoMaterials t " & vbCrLf & _
         "WHERE t.PONumber = [Forms]![FrmProductionEdit]![PONumber] " & vbCrLf & _
         "  AND t.ProductionDate = [Forms]![FrmProductionEdit]![Zdate] " & vbCrLf & _
         "  AND t.AcceptedNumber = [Forms]![FrmProductionEdit]![AcceptedProduct] " & vbCrLf & _
         "  AND t.RejectedNumber = [Forms]![FrmProductionEdit]![RejectedProduct] " & vbCrLf & _
         "  AND t.Shift = [Forms]![FrmProductionEdit]![Shift];"
    
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Better yet (and more efficient), save the long SQL as a stored query object without VBA grammar (`&`, `"`, `_`, or `vbCrLf`) and simply run (no need to close an action query):

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedDeleteQuery"
```

Answer (score 0):

About the error message it’s gone after i added `dim x as integer` the declaration was in wrong place in the code thanks